# Android Studio Execution failed for task compilefreeDebugKotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

## Kotlin Android Gradle

I can't compile my Kotlin Android application

I have gradle build faile with error:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compilefreeDebugKotlin'.
    > com.android.build.gradle.api.BaseVariant.getProcessResources()Lcom/android/build/gradle/tasks/ProcessAndroidResources;
```

In my project, I described a simple adapter

```
import android.widget.TextView
import android.content.Context
import java.util.ArrayList
import com.idunnololz.widgets.AnimatedExpandableListView
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.LayoutInflater

    public class ExpListAdapter(vcontext: Context, vgroups: ArrayList<String>, vtitles: ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) : AnimatedExpandableListView.AnimatedExpandableListAdapter() {
    var titles = vtitles
    var context = vcontext
    var groups = vgroups
    override fun getGroupCount(): Int = titles.size()
    override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Any = titles.get(groupPosition)
    override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Any = titles.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)
    override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long = groupPosition.toLong()
    override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long = childPosition.toLong()
    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean = true
    override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int, isExpanded: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
        var convertView = convertView

        if ( convertView == null) {
            val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_parent, parent, false)
        }


        val textGroup = convertView?.findViewById(R.id.tv_parent_size) as TextView
        textGroup.setText(groups.get(groupPosition))
        val textGroupnum = convertView?.findViewById(R.id.tv_parent_numbet) as TextView
        textGroupnum.setText(java.lang.String.valueOf(groupPosition + 1))
        return convertView as View
    }

    override fun getRealChildView(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int, isLastChild: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View? {
        var convertView = convertView
        if (convertView == null) {
            val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_childer, parent, false)
        }
        val textChild = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.tv_children_name) as TextView
        textChild.setText(titles.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition))
        return convertView as View
    }

    override fun getRealChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int = titles.get(groupPosition).size()
    override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Boolean = true
}
```

For compile I'm used default gradle build script and Android Studio 1.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update `kotlin-gradle-plugin` version to 0.9.976 in `build.gradle` file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.9.976'
    }
}
```